# How to make my bash script to start from past 6 months and run consecutively thereafter?

Tags: bash, shell

```
MONTH=`date '6 month ago' %Y-%m`
MONTH1=`date '5 month ago' %Y-%m`
MONTH2=`date '4 month ago' %Y-%m`
MONTH3=`date '3 month ago' %Y-%m`
MONTH4=`date '2 month ago' %Y-%m`
MONTH5=`date '1 month ago' %Y-%m`
MONTH6=`date %Y-%m`
```

How do i make the script run consecutively as it stops running at the current month? Start from 2013-07 till the current month 2014-01 and it keeps on adding for the consecutive months.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Vahid abdi How do i make a loop for the months from the past 6 months to run consecutively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a fancier invocation of `date`. Here's  10 months, adjust accordingly for the amount of future months you need:

```
day=$(date -d '6 months ago' +%F)

for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do 
    month=${day%-*}
    echo $month
    day=$(date -d "$day + 1 month" +%F)
done
```

```
2013-07
2013-08
2013-09
2013-10
2013-11
2013-12
2014-01
2014-02
2014-03
2014-04
```

`%F` is the same as `%Y-%m-%d`